# How do I pause Java Simulation using Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, simulation

Okay I have a simulation running. I have implemented two JButtons which actionListeners on the GUI of my simulation. What I want is to have the whole simulation to pause if I press the pause button and to resume if I press the resume button.

There are multiple threads running, and I have tried to get each of the threads and invoke their wait() method when the pause button is clicked but I have not been successful in doing so.

Hence, I need some advice on how to do this. I'm using Swing for the GUI and the listeners work fine. I did try to invoke a sleep() and wait() on the current thread in the View class (using MVC pattern) just to see what happened but that caused the whole application to crash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide additional logic to your simulation thread that will accept "signals" from controlling (GUI) thread and wait for the next controlling signal to resume execution.

For example you can use `volatile boolean isPaused` instance field in simulation thread. Set it to true/false to pause/resume simulation thread. In simulation thread implement corresponding logic:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        simulate();
        while (isPaused) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the thread will be waking up every 100 milliseconds, which uses processor time.. Better to use `wait()` and `notify()` which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I think wait/notify are better for very concurrent environment. For his simple task this solution will do the job

Answer (score 2):

If the animation is using a Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) the simple answer would be to call [`stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#stop%28%29).

I highly recommend using the `Timer` for animation since it ensures the actions are performed on the EDT.

Comment: Conversely, if the OP has a simulation as stated in the question, then running it on the EDT is a bad idea, as simulations tend to be processor heavy and would cause the application to be non-responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a `ThreadGroup` to store all your threads, then try to use

`ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread( ).getThreadGroup( );`

By the way, `ExecutorService` is a good choice, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared object to communicate between the two classes. Then have your gui set the value of the state object when the button is clicked, and change it again when it's clicked again. Here's some sample code:

```java
public class Simulation implements Runnable {
  private State myState = null;

  public Simulation(State myState) {
    this.myState = myState;
  }

  public void run() {
    while(myState != null) {
      if (myState.isPaused()) myState.wait();
      // Do other stuff
    }
  }
}

public class MainClass implements ActionListener() {
  private State myState = new MyState();

  private void beginSimulation() {
    Simulation s = new Simulation(this.myState());
    new Thread(s).start();
  }  

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(myState.isPaused()) {
      myState.setPaused(false);
      myState.notify();
    } else {
      myState.setPaused(true);
    }
  }
}

public class MyState() {
  private boolean paused = false;
  public MyState(boolean paused) { this.paused = paused; }
  public boolean getPaused() { return paused; }
  public void setPaused(boolean paused) { this.paused = paused; }
}
```